# IOS Safari window open on touchstart or touchend

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, window.open, touchstart

This code is working in most android/chrome mobile browsers:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
    //alert(1);
    window.open("http://test.com");
}, false)
```

But it is not working in `iOS/Safari (tested with iPhone OS 9_2, AppleWebKit 601.1.46, Safari/601.1).`

*Is there any workaround to show a new window/tab with this event?*

`"alert(1)"` is working fine, so i suppose the event is firing normally.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that since iOS >= 9.0, you can no longer use window.open inside a "touchstart" event handler function. You can use the click instead.

I iOS 8.x you can still open a page with window.open in a "touchstart" event handler function